# SharePoint Multistage Approver Workflow

Tags: sharepoint-online, workflow

I am really new to workflows in SharePoint. I'm just messing around and trying to create simple ones.

I want to create a workflow where:

1. User A drops a template into a library
2. This triggers an email off to User B alerting them the template is in
3. User B then adds content to the template
4. User B sends it off to user C to review/Comments
5. User C sends back comments or approves
6. Once approved and email will go to User D who can add comments and also reject/approve
7. Once user D has marked it as approved the workflow ends

Can I do this with multiple workflows? I am really finding workflows confusing. Any good links or advice would be a real help. I am searching and not really finding any help for my scenario.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Best approach is to have **one single workflow** set to run on change (in case one to run on creation to set up the base values), and instead create **different forms** (html forms, not infopath) based on users different needs, but all feeding the same list.
To set up the approval I suggest you to create **columns** (choice or yes/not) for each step, and the workflow verify both the filled fields and the approval status. and in case sends alert (email) to the next/previous actor.
Rather than having several workflow, you better **split it in stages and steps**. In case you can use 2010 sub-workflows, but I think the best approach is to have one single well designed 2013 wf.
I am creating several WFs for my work and they are reliable and flexible (however sometimes may become slow...), but unfortunately I cannot show them.

Comment: Hey thanks so much. Its a start. I think I just need to break it down in to stages one by one and add to them. I am using Sharepoint 2013. Would workflow approval or a three stage be best. Thanks again for coming back so quickly. Really appreciate it.

Comment: You should measure if the OOB workflows meet your needs. Honestly I never use them because they are not flexible and finally it is not difficult to create an approval stage within a workflow. The really tricky part is to learn how to create good forms with the SPD - but this is another topic. If you have found useful the answer, please set it up. Thanks